# How to scan a grid to replace only a certain character?

Tags: c

I want a function that ends my program after changing all CSHIPS ('.') to REVEALEDCSHIPS ('C') and displaying them.
The problem is that all SEA squares are also turned into REVEALEDCSHIPS, but should of course stay SEA.
The value for SEA is also defined as '.', if that makes a difference.
Find my code environmet below.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<strings.h>

#define MAXGRIDSIZE 15
#define SEA '.'
#define PSHIP 'P'
#define SUNKENPSHIP 'B'
#define CSHIP '.'
#define BOMB '*'
#define SUNKENCSHIP 'V'
#define REVEALEDCSHIP 'C'
unsigned char grid[MAXGRIDSIZE][MAXGRIDSIZE];
int fleetSize;
void initGrid()
{
    int x, y;
    for(y=0; y<MAXGRIDSIZE; y++)
    {
        for(x=0; x<MAXGRIDSIZE; x++)
        {
            grid[y][x] = SEA;
        }
    }
}
void printGrid()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("\n");
    for(y=0; y<MAXGRIDSIZE; y++)
    {
        printf("%2d", y);
        for(x=0; x<MAXGRIDSIZE; x++)
        {
            printf("%3c", grid[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%2c", ' ');
    for(x=0; x<MAXGRIDSIZE; x++)
    {
            printf("%3d", x);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void placePShip()
{
    int x,y;
    printf("\nEnter Ship location: x , y: ");
    scanf("%d , %d", &x, &y);
    if (grid[y][x] == SEA)
    {
        grid[y][x] = PSHIP;
    }
}
void placeCShip(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    while ( 1 )
    {
        int a=rand()%15 ;
        int b=rand()%15 ;
        if (grid[a][b] == SEA)
        {
            grid[a][b] = CSHIP;
            break ;
        }
    }
}
void placeShips()
{
    int i;
    printf("\nEnter fleet size : ");
    scanf("%d", &fleetSize);
    if(fleetSize>122)
    {
        printf("\nThat size is too large to fit in grid, select a smaller number");
        placeShips();
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<fleetSize;i++)
    {
        placePShip();
        placeCShip();
        printGrid();        
    }
}
void quit()
{
    int x,y;
    for(y=0;y<MAXGRIDSIZE;y++)
    {
        if(grid[y][x] == CSHIP){grid[y][x] = REVEALEDCSHIP;}
        for(x=0;x<MAXGRIDSIZE;x++)
        {
            if(grid[y][x] == CSHIP)
            {
                grid[y][x] = REVEALEDCSHIP;
            }
        }
    }
    printGrid();
    printf("\n>>GG, here are all remaining ships");
}
int main()
{
    initGrid();
    printGrid();
    placeShips();
    quit();
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, because what you seem to ask help with is what you have successfully done twice already inside printGrid() and initGrid(). If you want to do the `if(grid[y][x] == CSHIP){
           grid[y][x] = REVEALEDCSHIP}` on each square in the grid, then do it with the same nested loop construct as the other two things. Why is that not possible?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to write `REVEALEDSHIP` into each grid location which is equal to `CSHIP`, which is defined to `'.'`). But if the grid location contains `SEA`, which is also defined to `'.'`, then you want it to remain `SEA`? I think you might be doomed, because `if(grid[y][x] == CSHIP)` will evaluate to true in both cases, whether you wrote `SEA` or `CSHIP` to it does not matter. In both cases the `grid[y][x] = REVEALEDCSHIP` will be executed.

Comment: This is too much guessing. Please make a [mre], showing the output of a grid with a few concealed ships, a few revealed ships and los of sea. I.e. one which first calls `ìnitGrid()`, then `printGrid()`, then adds a few hardoced concealed ships and a few hardcoded revealed ships, `printGrid()`again and then call the function `quit()`; the goal of which seems clear to me. I need the MRE, to see whether my pessimistic understanding of your description is correct. I think you need to use different values for CSHIP and SEA and then change `printGrid()` to print both as `'.'`.

Comment: You need different values, not only different names for the same value.

Comment: @Yunnosch Got an MRE in for you, lets you pick fleet size and place player co ords and when done prints with a replacement, I have CSHIP set to 'C' in this but you can change it to '.' to see how everything changes to the revealedcship value

Comment: OK, in contrast to what you wrote earlier `CSHIP` and `SEA` are NOT identical values. This is another reason for always providing an MRE. Now, make an MRE which demonstrates your problem. Please hard-code a grid which demonstrates it, instead of making one which asks me for input. You provide the data which demonstrates, please. Then show the output it produces and explain what is not OK. By the way, you can delete the first `if(){}` inside `quit()` it is useless AND uses a non-initialised x.

Comment: I fixed your inconsistent indentation. For the kind of structure-oriented analysis needed here that is very important. I took some liberty on the style, the aligned `{}` are my favorite, to highlight the indentation levels which support the structural analysis.

Comment: Other lines which seem free of purpose to me: `char op;` , `exit(0);` , `placeShips();
        return;` (which are dangerously recursive; they can be deleted if the enclosing `if` is turned into a `do-while` which includes the `scanf()`).

Comment: The `quit()` is different in the big MRE and in the standalone version. Main difference: The one in the MRE probably seems to work on the outside. Did you try? Make sure to init x if you try (or delete the first if).

Comment: @Yunnosch CSHIPS and SEA were only different values because I had changed to check everything else works, remembered to set them both to '.' now. The input is just any integer>122 (1 is easiest) and then co ords (eg: 3,4), after which CSHIP is placed and quit auto runs. The problem I'm running into is that quit turns SEA and CSHIP into REVEALEDCSHIPS instead of just CSHIP, unless I give CSHIP a different value. How would I change printGrid() to print both as '.' while they have different values like you suggested?

Comment: Sigh. That is precisely what I said. SEA and CSHIP are handled the same (both turned into REVEALEDCSHIPS) exactly **because** the values are the same. Undo that and it will work. If you want them to look the same to the player, then change the printGrid() function to output the same for the two different values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different values for SEA and CSHIP;
because using different names/synonyms/macros for the same value does not help.
Anything that is identical to CSHIP (being defined to `'.'`) would also be identical to SEA (being also defined  to `'.'`) and hence the code would react for SEA and CSHIP like for CSHIP, i.e. turn SEA into REVEALEDCSHIP, too.

```c
#define SEA '.'
/* this one gets shown to the player directly */

#define CSHIP 'H' 
/* this one needs to be kept secret from the player during game, see below */
```

In order to make them look the same for the player during the game (before revealing them inside `quit()`), change the `printGrid()` function to show them identically, while knowing the difference:

```c
void printGrid()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("\n");
    for(y=0; y<MAXGRIDSIZE; y++)
    {
        printf("%2d", y);
        for(x=0; x<MAXGRIDSIZE; x++)
        {
            if(CSHIP == grid[y][x])   /* do not show like this */
            {    printf("%3c", SEA);  /*   camouflage instead  */
            } else
            {    printf("%3c", grid[y][x]); /* others directly */
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%2c", ' ');
    for(x=0; x<MAXGRIDSIZE; x++)
    {
            printf("%3d", x);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Then your `quit()` function should work, here are just some cleanups:

```c
void quit()
{
    /* always init, just for safety */
    int x=0;
    int y=0;

    for(y=0;y<MAXGRIDSIZE;y++)
    {
        /*  unneeded, and did use previously non-initialised x
            if(grid[y][x] == CSHIP){grid[y][x] = REVEALEDCSHIP;}
         */
        for(x=0;x<MAXGRIDSIZE;x++)
        {
            if(grid[y][x] == CSHIP)
            {
                grid[y][x] = REVEALEDCSHIP;
            }
        }
    }
    printGrid();
    printf("\n>>GG, here are all remaining ships.\n"); /* newline, to ensure output */
}
```